# how to write hql with in clauses

Tags: hql

I need to write an hql query like :

```
select * from User aliasUser where ? in aliasUser.roles
```

All examples of IN clause I'm finding use collection as parameters, how can I write this query? Obviously doesn't work as it stands right now, I've tried already.

Comment: what do you give as parameter, what is the value of "?" is it role.id or role.name ... ??

Comment: role.id, the mappings are really standard. User has a collection of Role, that maps using role.id.

Comment: so you want the list of users which have the given role ??

Comment: yes, and one user can have multiple roles. It has to match any of them.

Comment: I will need to see the two entities, does the role entity has list of users ??